# Eclipse lost shortcut for inspect while debugging ctrl+shift+i

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, shortcut, inspect

I'm trying to restore a shortcut with no succcess. There were a shortcut to do inspect, by clicking CTRL+SHIFT+I. But just now i have no more available this feature, it seems to be disappeared.

Any idea to restore it? Thanks!!

Comment: If you right-click the variable while debugging (given you already stopping at the breakpoint, otherwise it won't work), there should be "Inspect" and its shortcut. Are you able to see it? *(btw, nice shortcut, I just knew it)*

Comment: Yes, of course, that is the "classical way" and by now i do in this way, but while you are able to see the shortcut (ctrl+shift+i) i don't... I mean, some days ago i could also see the shortcut by  right clicking, but after installing some plugins, it dissappeared

Comment: Hmm, it might have something to do with your plugin. Perhaps it overwrote the shortcut? Maybe try uninstall it first? I don't really know how plugin interacts with shortcut...

Comment: it seems to be related with the plugin...i'll try to uninstall it and see...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally i figured out how to restore this command:

[image]

To reach this pannel you have to go: Windows->Preferences->General->Keys and restore like shows the picture.

Comment: Photo link is dead